# Find dy/dx, simplifying the coefficients of each term.

Tags: derivatives, multinomial-coefficients

The equation: $5x-7+2x^{-1/2}+3x^{-1}$.

I got $dy/dx=5-x^{-3/2}-3x^{-2}$. Firstly is this correct? But more importantly, what does it mean by simplify the coefficients... are they not already simplified.

It was a 4 mark question and I did it in very few steps leading me to think I have missed something out.

Comment: You differentiated correctly, and  i think simplifing means reducing fractions with common denominators.

Comment: @John.P so would you say I have already simplified it?

Comment: Kind of, but I would rather say $\frac{5x^2-\sqrt{x}-3}{x^2}$ would be a little bit nice.